# Non type-variable argument in the constraint when using >>= operator

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I have this simple code:

```
module Matrix where

matrix :: a -> (Int, Int) -> [[a]]
matrix x (width, height) = replicate height (replicate width x)

mapMatrix :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
mapMatrix f m = map (map f) m
```

When I do:

```
mapMatrix (+1) (matrix 0 (2,2))
```

I get, as expected:

> [[1,1],[1,1]]

Probably I'm misunderstanding monads and/or the `>>=` operator but I was expecting the following to have the same output:

```
matrix 0 (2,2) >>= mapMatrix (+1)
```

Instead I get:

> Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [b]
>      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this) When checking the inferred type
>       It :: forall b. (Num [b], Num b) => [[b]]

How can I write `mapMatrix (+1) (matrix 0 (2,2))` with monads, so I can read and write the code from left-to-right instead of in-to-out because as you can imagine, I'm planning on using `mapMatrix` a lot on the same matrix, something like:

```
matrix ... >>= mapMatrix ... >>= mapMatrix .. >>= ...
```

Comment: `f x` is never the same as `x >>= f`, just as `f 1` is not the same as `1 + f`: `>>=` is an operator that does a specific thing.

Comment: @amalloy So I'm using the wrong operator? What I'm looking for specifically is the classic `bind` operation that you get when using monads, at least as I learnt them in other languages. By the way I'm doing this just for learning purposes, but I could really use some guidance right now

Comment: Indeed >>= is the monad bind operation but the monad bind operation doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Mh, I always thought of `bind` as `bind(x, f) <=> f(x)` or even `x.bind(f) <=> f(x)`, I guess I have to learn the specifics of Haskell.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo Indeed that is not the case in general. Perhaps you are looking for `(&)` (in `Data.Function`)? That is defined as `x & f = f x`.

Comment: @Alec Indeed that was exactly what I was looking for! Feel free to write the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This not what a monad is supposed to do. You are likely interested in [`(&) :: a -> (a -> b)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-) defined in `Data.Function`.

```
matrix ... & mapMatrix ... & mapMatrix .. & ...
```

---

Note that the signature of bind is

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

and one cannot simply ignore the `m`s.

For completeness, note that one actually *can* make bind behave almost the way you want it to using one particular monad: [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html). It takes a bit of wrapping/unwrapping the constructor though.

```
module Matrix where

import Data.Functor.Identity

matrix :: a -> (Int, Int) -> Identity [[a]]
matrix x (width, height) = Identity $ replicate height (replicate width x)

mapMatrix :: (a -> b) -> [[a]] -> Identity [[b]]
mapMatrix f m = Identity $ map (map f) m
```

Then, the following works too:

```
runIdentity (matrix ... >>= mapMatrix ... >>= mapMatrix .. >>= ...)
```

Comment: The note about `Identity` is crucial here, I usually implement `bind` in other languages extending the native root type with a `bind` method, I guess that's making the root type behave somewhat like the Identity monad does in your example. Thats why everybody should try Haskell, you learn a lot about the proper way to do functional programming.